# Is it possible to play sounds without stopping iPod music?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, ipod

Is it possible to play sounds within an app without stopping iPod music?

Right now I'm using the following, but it stops iPod music

```
soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySound" ofType:@"mp3"];
soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];   
mySound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
[mySound prepareToPlay];
```

and then

```
[mySound play];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, you could use the following code

```
// setup session correctly
AVAudioSession *audiosession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audiosession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
OSStatus propertySetError = 0;

UInt32 mixingAllow = true;
propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty ( kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof (mixingAllow),&mixingAllow);

NSError *error = nil;
[audiosession setActive:YES error:&error];

// play sound
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
AVAudioPlayer *audioplayer = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&;error]autorelease];
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, or just

```
AVAudioSession *audiosession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audiosession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
```