# Simple way to play a sound without stopping music iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to play sounds without stopping iPod music?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036748/is-it-possible-to-play-sounds-without-stopping-ipod-music)

Is there a simple way to play a sound without stopping music? I'm trying to make a metronome app if you have any suggestions they would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about playing a sound without interrupting music from the iPod/Music app?  If so, you need to configure your audio session category to allow mixing with the `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers` property.

See [Is it possible to play sounds without stopping iPod music?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036748/is-it-possible-to-play-sounds-without-stopping-ipod-music?rq=1) for sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: Create a player class to wrap the initialization (uses AVFoundation.framework).

Source:

```
#import "MyAVAudioPlayer.h"

@implementation MyAVAudioPlayer

-(id)initWithFile:(NSString*)strFile
{
    NSError *err;
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:strFile];
    self = [super initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] 
                                  error:&err];
    if(err)
    {
        NSLog(@"Loading of %@ Failed with reason: %@", strFile,
              [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Loaded %@", strFile);
        [self prepareToPlay];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Header:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface MyAVAudioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer
{
}
-(id)initWithFile:(NSString*)strFile;
@end
```

Usage:

```
MyAVAudioPlayer *player = [[MyAVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithFile:@"yoursound.mp3"];
[player play]
```